# Recover Updated Data - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have an issue that, while using sql server 2005 i have executed update query without where clause (by mistake) and all the original values of the column get lost.

How can I get old values??

Any suggestion/tips/solution is welcome and will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Restore from backup. You have a backup, don't you?

Comment: this may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933065%28v=sql.80%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173522%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility. The database did exactly what you asked it to. Let this be a lesson: Don't execute any SQL in production without it being [peer reviewed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review) first.

Comment: I did not do it intentionally. Its by mistake. I forget to place the where clause. Instead giving a solution I have been suggested to update my resume. I thought its a good community but i was wrong. I believe everyone in the world do not works perfectly and they do this kind of mistakes. What they do in that case??? Thats why I am in this community otherwise I know i need to update my resume. I have backup of the DB but its older than a week and dozen of modification is done in between this time period.

Comment: The answer by user1059637 is excellent, it allow to recover the info updated with no problems, let's not judge if something is mess up, just try not to do it worst with not helpful comments.

Comment: you should check out this article: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-data-from-accidental-updates/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi AngelIII,
             SQL server keeps log for every transation.So you can recover your modified data from the log as well without backup.

```
Select [PAGE ID],[Slot ID],[AllocUnitId],[Transaction ID] ,[RowLog Contents 0]
, [RowLog Contents 1],[RowLog Contents 3],[RowLog Contents 4] ,[Log Record]
FROM    sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)   
WHERE AllocUnitId IN 
(Select [Allocation_unit_id] from sys.allocation_units allocunits 
INNER JOIN sys.partitions partitions ON (allocunits.type IN (1, 3)   
AND partitions.hobt_id = allocunits.container_id) 
OR (allocunits.type = 2 AND partitions.partition_id = allocunits.container_id)   
Where object_id=object_ID('' + 'dbo.student' + '')) 
AND Operation in ('LOP_MODIFY_ROW','LOP_MODIFY_COLUMNS')  
And [Context] IN   ('LCX_HEAP','LCX_CLUSTERED')
```

Here is the artcile, that explains step by step, how to do it. http://raresql.com/2012/02/01/how-to-recover-modified-records-from-sql-server-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

1. Restore a backup taken before the update
2. Restore transaction logs to a point in time before the update
3. Restore a copy of the table you made before the update
4. Rollback the transaction that contains the update

It's difficult to offer a specific solution not knowing what precautions you have taken. These may not solve your problem, but may prevent this from happening in the future.

DON'T MESS AROUND WITH SQL THAT ALTERS PRODUCTION DATA UNTIL YOU HAVE ANSWERED THIS QUESTION.