# Recover deleted and truncate data of a SQL table

Tags: sql

I have deleted rows in a SQL table, now I want to recover those deleted rows, or I truncated all data of a SQL table. Please tell me that how can I recover truncated or deleted data of any SQL table using any stored procedure..

Comment: Which DBMS u r using? Oracle,SQL Server....?

Comment: Gently ask your administrator for a restoration of the last backup?

Comment: I Guess if the commit commend has been executed it cannot be retracted unless you have a database/table backup. As you db admin may be?

Comment: Perhaps having a look at this thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053805/recover-updated-data-sql-server-2005